# NOSTR NIP-05 Send get request parameter to a json file and return an appropriate response

Tags: php, json, apache, mod-rewrite

[NIP-05](https://github.com/nostr-protocol/nips/blob/master/05.md) **Mapping Nostr keys to DNS-based internet identifiers** describes a requirement to be able to handle GET requests to a .json file. For obvious security reason I want to return a json only if requested name exists; otherwise return an error.

Let's say I have a nostr.json file that looks like this

```
{
  "names": {
    "user_name_1": "user_pubkey_1",
    "user_name_2": "user_pubkey_2"
  },
  "relays": {
    "user_pubkey_1": [ "wss://relay1", "wss://relay2" ],
    "user_pubkey_2": [ "wss://relay3", "wss://relay4" ]
  }
}
```

Request from a Nostr relay is: https://example.com/.well-known/nostr.json?name=user_name_1
and what I want is to return the appropriate response

```
{
  "names": {
    "user_name_1":"user_pubkey_1"
  },
  "relays": {
    "user_pubkey_1":[ "wss://relay1", "wss://relay2" ]
  }
}
```

only in case the name exists; otherwise return

```
{
  "error":"user not found"
}
```

or in case of a wrong GET parameter return

```
{
  "error":"Missing name parameter"
}
```

What is the best way to do it?

**Edit:**
Found a working [example](https://getalby.com/.well-known/nostr.json?name=williamsantiago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way around is to `RewriteRule` to point to some `secret_name.php` file.